# AngularJS - How to avoid using the same expression

Tags: angularjs, expression

I want to show the result of a function styled according to the result and only within certain limits:

```
<div 
ng-if="myFunction(a,b)<1000"
ng-style="myFunction(a,b)<0 && {'color':'red'} || {'color': 'lime'}">
    {{myFunction(a,b)}}
</div>
```

myFunction(a,b) is quite heavy and have some loops inside it.

How can I avoid calling myFunction(a,b) three times in the example above? The values of a and b may change and the function must update it's result.

**Edited as per Alon Eitan comment:**

So is this the way to go?

```
$scope.$watch('a', function() {
  $scope.result = $scope.myFunction(a,b);
});
$scope.$watch('b', function() {
  $scope.result = $scope.myFunction(a,b);
});

<div 
ng-if="result<1000"
ng-style="result<0 && {'color':'red'} || {'color': 'lime'}">
    {{result}}
</div>
```

Comment: how often will `myFunction()` be evaluated? if just once, then store the result in a`scope` variable.

Comment: You should bind scope properties to the view, not functions. [Read here](https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.4/docs/error/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5D) why